# How to enable auditing in wso2 identity server 5.1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to enable auditing via XDAS in wso2is.

**Question**

Is this possible?

---

**Question**

How can I enable xdas audit monitoring in admin console?

---

I can't find xdas feature in the installed features list.

**Question**

Why this feature not installed?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIaccesstheXDASauditinformationoftheWSO2IdentityServer?IsthereanyUserInterfaceforthis?),

> XDAS was only done in IS in a PoC level, and there's no immediate plan to integrate it into the Identity Server product as yet. The general audit logs of IS can be found at $IS_ROOT/repository/logs/audit.log

Comment: what's the meaning of PoC level?

Comment: I believe it means "Proof of Concept"